# Unable to use bash here document in rmarkdown chunk

Tags: r-markdown

I am using an R notebook to make a bash example. The problem occur when I try to execute the following code in a chunk: nothing happens. How can I fix this?

````
```{bash}
cat >text << "EOF"
a
b
12
EOF
```
````

Comment: It works for me: `text` file is created. If I add another `bash` chunk with `ls -l text`, I obtain info about the created file and if I add a `bash` chunk with `cat text`, I obtain the `text` file content.